# Debugger: show data of opencv Mat of type CV_16UC1

Tags: c++, opencv, gdb

I have an opencv Mat variable `img` of type `CV_16UC1` (16 bit memory with 12 bit usable data) and want to display its data member in the debugger, e.g. gdb. When I try to do `print img.data` I get:

```
print img
$2 = {flags = 1124024322, dims = 2, rows = 480, cols = 640, 
data = 0xa1b48042 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xa1b48042>, 
datastart = 0xa1b48042 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xa1b48042>, 
dataend = 0xa1bde042 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xa1bde042>, 
datalimit = 0xa1bde042 <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xa1bde042>, 
allocator = 0x0, u = 0x0, size = {p = 0xbeffeaa8}, step = {p = 0xbeffead0, buf = {1280, 2}}}
```

Trying to print values with `print *(ushort *)img.data@2` results in:

> Cannot access memory at address 0xa1b48042

How is it possible to display the values of `img` without converting to another type (e.g. `CV_8UC1`)?

`img` was create from a custom buffer class:

```
cv::Mat img = cv::Mat(height, width, CV_16UC1, (void *)(static_cast<char*>(buffer->Data()))
```

When I shift `img` by 4 bit and converting to `CV_8UC1`:

```
cv::Mat img8 = img * 16.0;
img8.convertTo(img8, CV_8UC1);
```

I am able to display the data with:

```
(gdb) print *(ushort *)img8.data@2
$5 = {513, 2052}
```

Comment: they added some [gdb "pretty printer" script](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/tree/4.x/samples/gdb) lately, have a look !

Comment: Thanks for the hint, I will have a look!